# Generate statistic by year and month in month

Tags: mysql, sql

last time i using interval, but i dont think it work like i want to,
 i just want to declare year and month.. any guru can teach me here?

```
DECLARE @YEAR AS INT = '2015',
 @MONTH AS INT = '1',
  @YEARTO AS INT = '2015',
   @MONTHTO AS INT = '1'


SELECT TYPE_FOOD, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) AS [INCOMING], COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS= 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS [OUTGOING],DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATE_OF_PURCHASE, @YEAR ) AS [YEAR]  
FROM Shop
GROUP BY TYPE_FOOD, DATEDIFF(MONTH,DATE_OF_PURCHASE, @YEAR )
```

my current query..

```
Food TYPE | MONTH | BUY | SELL 
 pizza       12     10     5       
 pizza       13      3     1       
 ....        ...     ..     ..     
 pizza       32     5      2
```

How to make sql like this:

```
Food TYPE | MONTH | BUY | SELL | CLEARANCE RATE %
 pizza       Jan-15     10    5        50%
 pizza       Feb-15     3     1        25%
 ....        ...     ..     ..      ..
 pizza       Dec-15     5      2        35%
```

and can i do clearance report inside sql too?

Answer (score 0):

Use date_format() function to get month and year from your date of purchase column:

```
SELECT TYPE_FOOD, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) AS INCOMING, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS= 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS OUTGOING,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_OF_PURCHASE, '%b-%Y') AS YEAR, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) * 100/COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS= 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS clearance_rate  
FROM Shop
GROUP BY TYPE_FOOD, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_OF_PURCHASE,'%b-%Y' )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TYPE_FOOD, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) AS [BUY], 
COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS= 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS [SELL],
MONTHNAME(DATE_OF_PURCHASE) AS [MONTH],
[INCOMING]*100/[OUTGOING] AS [CLEARANCE RATE %]
FROM Shop
GROUP BY TYPE_FOOD, [MONTH]
```

Comment: This is Sparta, aka myswl, not ms sql. Your solution will yield syntax errors.

Comment: it said there no incoming and outgoing table

Comment: Mysql as well as sql is mentioned in the question tags

Comment: Sql is s language,  ms sql is a product.